# Equivalent condition to analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I had the following shower-thought this morning:

> Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be given by 
>   $$
> f(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y)),
> $$
>   and let $g:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be the corresponding function satisfying
>   $$
> g(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y).
> $$
>   Let $U \subset \Bbb C$ be open (for convenience, we identify it with the corresponding
>   Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $g$ is analytic over $U$
> 2. For every $(x,y) \in U$, $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations
> 3. For every $(x,y) \in U$, there exists some $a + bi \in C$ such that the Jacobian map $Df(x,y):\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by
>      $$
>    Df(x,y)(\hat x, \hat y) = \pmatrix{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\[3 pt] \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}}\pmatrix{\hat x \\ \hat y}
>    $$
>      is just multiplication by the complex number $(a+bi)$.

**Proof:** $2 \iff 3$: set $a = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $b = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

---

My question is as follows: is this a useful or interesting perspective?  Is it common in some application of complex analysis?

I found [this section of a wiki article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Preservation_of_complex_structure) which is related but more specific than my point. If you could point me in the direction of a reference, that would be appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is very reminiscent of the "amplitwist" from Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469

Comment: @LordS Thanks! I'll take a look if I get the chance

Comment: Assuming $f$ differentiable over $\Bbb R^2 $, then identifying the real plane with the complex line and changing variables, the derivative (as a real linear map and with the given point we look at as origin) is $az + b\bar z$; complex differentiablity means precisely $b=0$ so the derivative becomes a complex linear map to, and this is exactly your condition $3$ - this persepctive is less useful here, but it is used more in several complex variables where it is far less "trivial"